# Error during a snowflake SQL installation

Tags: python

Trying to install SnowFlake SQL and it is giving me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
>   [1244] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

@Arularasu, think it is not a python issue as you tagged it but some issue with the Snowflake CLI Snowsql latest installer. Got the same error message with the current installer on a Windows machine.

Unistalled that one as referenced here:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-uninstall-SNOWSQL-on-Linux-and-Windows-OS

And then installed with an older installer that I had used for previous Snowsql installations (snowsql-1.1.85-windows_x86_64.msi) and it worked fine (in the first launch Snowsql will anyway upgrade to the latest version and that seems to work fine; it is probably then only about the current installer).